# Solve the following limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n+b}}{\sqrt{n+c}-\sqrt{n+d}},\textrm{   }  (c\neq d)$$ 
I really don't  know what to use to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Following your sugestions I get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n+b}}{\sqrt{n+c}-\sqrt{n+d}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+b}}{\sqrt{n+c}+\sqrt{n+d}}\left(\frac{a-b}{c-d}\right)=\left(\frac{a-b}{c-d}\right)$$

That should be it, thanks.

Comment: Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator with $\sqrt{n+c}+\sqrt{n+d}$

Comment: Another idea is to try binomial expansion for a few terms.

Comment: Also, multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n+b}$.

Comment: @Galc127 I presume you mean do this in addition to what gammatester suggests - carefully done that helps a lot.

Comment: @MarkBennet, of course. We need to do both in order to evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After factoring out by $\sqrt{n}$ and simplifying,

and with

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n}}=1+\frac{a}{2n}(1+\epsilon(n)),$$

we get the limit

$$\frac{a-b}{c-d}$$